# How to Display 4 Triangle Patterns Side by Side

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble getting 4 different triangle patterns to appear side by side. This is a console application program.

This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve through the use of nested for loops:

```
*         ********************         *
**        *********  *********        **
***       ********    ********       ***
****      *******      *******      ****
*****     ******        ******     *****
******    *****          *****    ******
*******   ****            ****   *******
********  ***              ***  ********
********* **                ** *********
***********                  ***********
```

I already have the individual patterns working already, but of course they appear one after the other.

```
using System;

class Assignment5
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) // Inner loop for number of stars
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } // End First Pattern

        for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) // Outer loop for number of rows
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) // Inner loop for number of stars
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } // End Second Pattern

        for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) // Outer Loop for number of rows
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10 - i; j++)         //Inner loop for number of spaces
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)  //Secondary inner loop for number of stars
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        } // End Third Pattern

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)               //Outer Loop for number of rows
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10 - i; j++)         //Inner loop for number of spaces
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)  //Secondary inner loop for number of stars
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } // End Fourth Pattern

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter for Part 2 of this Program");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

    } // End main function


} // End class Assignment5
```

Comment: You need to write the first line of all of them, then the second line of all of them, and so on.

Comment: OR you could move the cursor... But I'm not sure what would happen if the screen scrolls :-)

Comment: It's a console based program and yes it was a homework assignment. I turned in without this half, but I'm still curious how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify *how* you wanted to implement, so I present you with:

```
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
@"*         ********************         *
**        *********  *********        **
***       ********    ********       ***
****      *******      *******      ****
*****     ******        ******     *****
******    *****          *****    ******
*******   ****            ****   *******
********  ***              ***  ********
********* **                ** *********
***********                  ***********");
        }
```

[EDIT] Ok, here's a less facetious answer. ;)

```
int n = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        Console.Write("*");

    for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; ++j)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (int j = 0; j < n-i; ++j)
        Console.Write("*");

    for (int j = 0; j < 2*i; ++j)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (int j = 0; j < n-i; ++j)
        Console.Write("*");

    for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; ++j)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        Console.Write("*");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[Second edit]

It would be more readable to write methods for outputting `n` stars or spaces, like so:

```
static void stars(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        Console.Write("*");
}

static void spaces(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        Console.Write(" ");
}
```

And then:

```
int n = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    stars(i+1);
    spaces(n-i-1);
    stars(n-i+1);
    spaces(2*i);
    stars(n-i);
    spaces(n-i-1);
    stars(i+1);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes after viewing the first few comments I quickly realized this. Edits have been made with more specific information.

Comment: The lines are palindromes so you only have to create the first half and than add the reverse of that. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18099431/44620

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brain teaser for you.

```
for (int n = 10; n > 0; n--)
{
    var tri = "".PadRight(11 - n, '*').PadRight(10, ' ') + "".PadRight(n, '*').PadRight(10, ' ');
    Console.WriteLine(tri + String.Join("", tri.ToCharArray().Reverse()));
}
```

Output:

```
*         ********************         *
**        *********  *********        **
***       ********    ********       ***
****      *******      *******      ****
*****     ******        ******     *****
******    *****          *****    ******
*******   ****            ****   *******
********  ***              ***  ********
********* **                ** *********
***********                  ***********
```

Comment: Nice, but the OP is doing homework for which the requirement is `through the use of nested for loops`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the required result.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            for (int k = 10; k >= i; k--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }            
            for (int l = 10-i; l >= 0; l--)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <= i*2; k++) 
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 10-i; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            for (int k = 10; k >= i; k--) 
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        } 

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int length = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string result = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                     fillWithStarFromLeft(i + 1, length),
                     fillWithStarFromLeft(length - i, length),
                     fillWithStarFromRight(length - i, length),
                     fillWithStarFromRight(i + 1, length)
                     );

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static object fillWithStarFromRight(int length, int segmentlength)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result += "*";
            }

            return result.PadLeft(segmentlength, ' ');
        }

        private static string fillWithStarFromLeft(int length, int segmentlength)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result += "*";
            }

            return result.PadRight(segmentlength, ' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Just a quick though hope it helps

Comment: This was actually really interesting to walk though. I'm still trying to get used to the concepts of OOP so this is a really nice example of how to implement in an OO way instead of procedural.

Comment: Glad it helped , also notice that if u just change the lenght in "int length = 10;" you get the same shape with more stars ( without changing anything else )

Comment: To be honest this solution has nothing that would boast about being an OOP solution. Just a class with some static methods and those are definitely not what OOP is about. No offence to the author though as he didnt claim that it is one.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` commands which are writing at the current cursor position. Your loops are always working in a 10*10 character range, followed by a newline.

An approach to your problem would be absolute cursor position, setting the cursor to the right position and then drawing one character. Each subsequent triangle must be moved by a offset:

```
int leftOffset = 0;

// draw first triangle
for x in ...
   for y in ...
      Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
      Console.Write("*");

leftOffset += 10;

// draw second triangle
for x in ...
   for y in ...
      Console.SetCursorPosition(x + leftOffset, y);
      Console.Write("*");

.
.
.
```

Be sure to clean the console before you start!

Comment: I don't think moving cursor is necessary. With proper use of math, you can achieve the pattern line by line.

Comment: I didn't down vote this. I appreciate that you attempted to help me with this, and I apologize for the lack of clarity in the original post.

Comment: @jnovacho this is right. As you can read in my preamble, I only suggest one possible solution.

Comment: @jnovacho with the cursor move you can implement a much more generic solution for this problem, drawing these triangles dynamically at a random position.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: you create an array with all the '*' and then you display it.

I have used a 3 dimensional array: row, column, pattern number. 
I have even shifted everything in the 0 < x < 10, because in the world of C and C# arrays are 0-based.
Notice that I fill even the "blank" spaces of the array.

```
static void Main()
{
    var chars = new char[10, 10, 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i >= j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 0] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i, j, 0] = ' ';
            }
        }
    } // End First Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i <= 9 - j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 1] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i, j, 1] = ' ';
            }
        }
    } // End Second Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i <= j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 2] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i, j, 2] = ' ';
            }
        }
    } // End Third Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 9 - j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 3] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i, j, 3] = ' ';
            }
        }
    } // End Fourth Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(chars[i, j, k]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter for Part 2 of this Program");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();

} // End main function
```

As I told you, I filled empty spaces with space during the array creation. I could have skipped it and instead replaced the spaces that are `chars[i, j, k] == 0` with `' '` in the Console.Write, like:

```
static void Main()
{
    var chars = new char[10, 10, 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i >= j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 0] = '*';
            }
        }
    } // End First Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i <= 9 - j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 1] = '*';
            }
        }
    } // End Second Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i <= j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 2] = '*';
            }
        }
    } // End Third Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 9 - j)
            {
                chars[i, j, 3] = '*';
            }
        }
    } // End Fourth Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (chars[i, j, k] != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(chars[i, j, k]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(' ');
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter for Part 2 of this Program");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();

} // End main function
```

From there we could remove the `if` and make them part of the `for`, but it becomes quite unreadable...

```
static void Main()
{
    var chars = new char[10, 10, 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            chars[i, j, 0] = '*';
        }
    } // End First Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++)
        {
            chars[i, j, 1] = '*';
        }
    } // End Second Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = i; j < 10; j++)
        {
            chars[i, j, 2] = '*';
        }
    } // End Third Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Outer loop for number of rows
    {
        for (int j = 9 - i; j < 10; j++)
        {
            chars[i, j, 3] = '*';
        }
    } // End Fourth Pattern

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (chars[i, j, k] != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(chars[i, j, k]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(' ');
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter for Part 2 of this Program");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();

} // End main function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (very short version)

```
int sz=10;
for (int i=0;i<sz;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<(sz*4);j++){
        if(j<=i || (j>=sz && j<=(sz*2)-(i+1))
        || (j>=sz*2 && j>=(sz*2)+i && j<sz*3)
        || (j>=(sz*4)-(i+1))
        )
        {
           Console.Write("*");
        }
        else {Console.Write(" ");}
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Typed here (Not tested). but this may do the trick!