# C# triangle pattern

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with printing triangle patterns in windows forms app making mirror image of the triangle below the first one.
I´m trying to achieve pattern 1 and 2 shown at

[How to Display 4 Triangle Patterns Side by Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097280/how-to-display-4-triangle-patterns-side-by-side/30220085#30220085)

connected together with bottom of the first one to the top of second.
If the user chooses 5 lines the triangle must have 10 lines

I've seen dozens of videos how to do it but none of them explains how to do it in forms application, all of them show the Console way.

this is the code for the first 5 lines

```
        txtoutput.Text = null;
        int lines = Convert.ToInt32(txtLines.Text);
        string hash = "#";

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            rTxtOutputD2.Text += hash + "\n";

            hash = hash + "#";
        }
```

can anybody help me with the mirror 5 lines ?

Comment: What is the *expected output*? Could you provide a sample(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the same procedure as the console one. But use a StringBuilder for the entire set of triangles. (e.g. `StringBuilder strTriangles = new StringBuilder()`)

But instead of writing to the console, add to the string, e.g. instead of `Console.Write("#")`, use `strTriangles.Append("#")`, and instead of using `Console.Writeline`, use `strTriangles.AppendLine()`.

Then add a label `lblTriangles` to your WinForm, and set `lblTriangles.Text = strTriangles.ToString()`.

Comment: I agree with this post. Assuming this is homework in a similar way than the question before it, I would suggest using StringBuilder. Basically every time you edit a string it creates a new object which can be cumbersome for the garbage collector. A string builder doesn't create any new objects when you edit it. You will have to call .ToString() to get it out though.

Comment: For this project it is probably not going to make a difference but it is good to know how things work in the background and that if you are doing lots of edits to a string it is usually better to use a stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

And to "mirror" the triangle...

```
    int lines = Convert.ToInt32(txtLines.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            rTxtOutputD2.Text += "#";
        }
        rTxtOutputD2.Text += "\n";
    }

    for (int i = lines; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            rTxtOutputD2.Text += "#";
        }
        rTxtOutputD2.Text += "\n";
    }
```

produces (for `lines` = 10)...

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
##########
##########
#########
########
#######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can´t belive this was so easy :P